# cant display all result from 2 table join with pivot table

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I have managed to join between 2 tables by using 1 pivot table(I have to), but I cant loop my way to get all of joined result, Bellow are:

Models
App.php

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class App extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'bas_app';
    public $timestamps = false;
    protected $fillable = ['id','app_name','app_type','description','menu_name','menu_url','menu_parent_id'];

    public function roles()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(Role::class,'bas_role_app','app_id','role_id');
    }

}
```

Role.php

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Role extends Model
{
    //
    protected $table = 'bas_role';
    protected $fillable = ['name','remark'];

    public function users()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\User','bas_user_role','role_id','user_id')
        ->withPivot('id');
    }

    public function apps()
    {
    //     return $this->belongsToMany(App::class,'bas_role_app','role_id','app_id')
    //     ->withPivot('id','priv_access','priv_insert','priv_delete',
    // 'priv_update','priv_export','priv_print','app_name');
    return $this->belongsToMany(App::class,'bas_role_app','role_id','app_id');
    }

}
```

RoleApp.php

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\Pivot;

class RoleApp extends Pivot
{
    //
    public $timestamps = false;
    protected $table = 'bas_role_app';
    protected $fillable = ['role_id','app_id','app_name'];

    public function b_app() {
        return $this->belongsToMany(App::class);
    }

    public function b_role() {
        return $this->belongsToMany(Role::class);
    }
}
```

Controller
RoleAppController.php

```
    namespace App\Http\Controllers;
    
    use Illuminate\Http\Request;
    use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Validator;
    use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;
    use Carbon\Carbon;
    use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Route;
    use App\User;
    use App\Role;
    use App\App;
    use App\ActivityLog;
    use App\RoleApp;
    use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Input;
    use DB;
    
    class RoleAppController extends Controller
    {
        public function __construct()
        {
            $this->middleware('auth');
        }
    
        public function display(Request $request)
        {
             $routes =  preg_match('/([a-z]*)@([a-z]*)/i', Route::currentRouteAction(), $matches);
             $routes = $matches[0];
             $action = $matches[2];
    
            if (Auth::check()) {
                DB::beginTransaction();
    
                try {
                $id = Auth::id();
                $profile_data = User::find($id);
                $RoleApp = Role::all();
            //$RoleApp->apps;
          //  dd($RoleApp);
          
    
                     ActivityLog::create([
    
                         'inserted_date' => Carbon::now()->TimeZone('asia/jakarta'),
                         'username' => $profile_data->username,
                         'application' => $routes,
                         'creator' => "System",
                         'ip_user' => $request->ip(),
                         'action' => $action,
                       'description' => "admin is looking at the role and application management",
                         'user_agent' => $request->server('HTTP_USER_AGENT')
                     ]);
    
                     DB::commit();
                 } catch (\Exception $ex) {
                     DB::rollback();
                 return response()->json(['error' => $ex->getMessage()], 500);
    
                 }
              //  return view('RoleApp', ['RoleApp' => $RoleApp]);
               return view('RoleApp', ['RoleApp' => $RoleApp]);
             } else {
                 return view("login");
             }
        }
}
```

View
RoleApp.blade.php

```
@extends('layouts.master')
@section('title','Display-RoleApp')
@section('content')


<div class="container mt-5">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-12">
            @if($errors->any())
            <div class="alert alert-danger alert-dismissible fade show" role="alert">
                {{ implode(', ', $errors->all(':message')) }}
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-label="Close">
                    <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                </button>
            </div>
            @endif
            <div class="float-right mb-5">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#exampleModalCenter">
                    Insert Role App
                </button>
            </div>




   <!-- Modal -->
   <div class="modal fade" id="exampleModalCenter" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalCenterTitle" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog modal-dialog-centered" role="document">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLongTitle">Insert User</h5>
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                    <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                </button>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                <form action="/roleapp/create" method="POST">
                    {{ csrf_field() }}

                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="role_name">role name:</label>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="role_name">
                    </div>

                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="app_name">app name:</label>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="app_name">
                    </div>

            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
            </div>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>


                <div class="table-responsive m-b-40">
            <table id="roleapp-table" class="table table-striped">
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th scope="col">Role Name</th>
                        <th scope="col">App Name</th>
                        <th scope="col" class="text-center">Action</th>
                        <th scope="col" class="text-center">Action</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody id="dynamic-row">
                    @foreach ($RoleApp->apps as $rp)
                    <tr>

                        <td>{{$RoleApp->name}}</td>
                        <td>{{$rp->app_name}}</td>

                        <td class="text-center">
                            <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#modal_ubah_{{$rp->id}}">Edit</button>
                        </td>
                        <td class="text-center">
                            <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#modal_hapus_{{$rp->id}}">Hapus</button>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    @endforeach
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
    var row = 0;
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('#user-table').DataTable({
            select: true,
            retrieve: true,
            "order": [
                [0, "desc"]
            ],
            "lengthMenu": [
                [20, 50, 100, 500, 1000, -1],
                [20, 50, 100, 500, 1000, "All"]
            ],
            "language": {
                "paginate": {
                    "next": ">",
                    "previous": "<"
                }
            }
        });
    });
    $('#user-table thead tr').clone(true).appendTo('#user-table thead');
    $('#user-table thead tr:eq(1) th').each(function(i) {
        if (row < 7) {
            var title = $(this).text();
            $(this).html('<input type="text" placeholder="Search ' + title + '" />');
        } else {
            $(this).html('');
        }
        row++;

        $('input', this).on('keyup change', function() {
            if (table.column(i).search() !== this.value) {
                table
                    .column(i)
                    .search(this.value)
                    .draw();
            }
        });
    });
</script>

@endsection
```

Any suggestion? I have tried various way and its still not working. I suspect that something is wrong in

```
$RoleApp = Role::all();
```

or

```
  @foreach ($RoleApp->apps as $rp)
                        <tr>
    
                            <td>{{$RoleApp->name}}</td>
                            <td>{{$rp->app_name}}</td>
    
                            <td class="text-center">
                                <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#modal_ubah_{{$rp->id}}">Edit</button>
                            </td>
                            <td class="text-center">
                                <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#modal_hapus_{{$rp->id}}">Hapus</button>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        @endforeach
```

if I try it with `$RoleApp = Role::find(2);` it will still work, but when i use get or all, it wont work.

Answer (score 0):

without eager loading.

```
$roles = Role::all();
```

with eager loading

```
$roles = Role::with('apps')->get();
```

$roles is a collection of model instances of Role Model. You can't access a property or relation of a model, on a collection. That is the reason it works when you use `find`(given model instance), and doesn't work for `all` or `get`(give collection).

You need to iterate over the collection and then access the relation like this.

```
foreach($roles as $role){
    // name of each role.
    $role->name;

   
    foreach($role->apps as $app){
       // name of each app associated with the $role.
       $app->name;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, it indeed solved my problem but for some reasons it just show 1 role with now apps despite with loops, and I cant loop the id for edit and delete button anymore, the error says "Trying to get property 'id' of non-object "

Comment: As per your models, role and apps have many to many relation. So each role will have multiple apps associated with it. foreach($roles as $role){ foreach($role->apps as $rp) {   $role->name; $rp->id;  } }

Comment: Tell me the format in you want to display the data, maybe i can help you out.

Comment: Its in tables, where I have 3 tables, role(id,name); app(id,app_name); and role_app(id,role_id,app_id). I want to show a data where I can know how much app that have been assign to a role, for example, admin have 2 apps related to it, like user_management and role_management, user have 2 apps that they can use, like myprofile and dashboard, and so on

Comment: Okay, so you just want to show the number of apps associated to a role?

Comment: role and the name of the apps associated to it, no null value and duplicate data allowed

Comment: I've updated the post, please check it. And if it's not the format you expected, please update the post to write the expected format so that it's clear to get the result.

Comment: And if the answer solves your problem, an upvote and acceptance is desirable :)